# About multi-user accounts, multiple programs in Ubuntu

Tags: users

I have just been using Ubuntu 14.04 for a few days...

Could anybody tell me whether:

If User A logs into the computer and installs an application, will then user B who logs into the same computer, be able to use the application User A installed???

Answer (score 1):

If using a [standard installation procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) then yes, User B will be able to use the software installed by User A.

There are however utilities that once installed locally will only work locally. (E.G. simple utilities installed in `/home/user/bin`)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: How do you make "check" symbol ?

Comment: @Liso Ask such questions in http://meta.askubuntu.com/ instead of the comments here...  **:P**

Comment: very understandable :)